# How do we get from $\int_0^x \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt$ to $1 - e^{-\lambda x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

This question is from Unit 1 Probability and random variables textbook provided by The Open University. We are trying to get the cumulative density function from the exponential distribution with the probability density function of
$f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x} $, $x>=0$.

I understand that I must integrate this function between $0$ and $x$, I have tried getting from
$\int_0^x \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt$ to $1 - e^{-\lambda x}$ using integration from parts, however I did not succeed. My background is in biology so I lack mathematical strength. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Integration by part ? What is the derivative of $e^{\lambda x}$ ?

Comment: The derivative of $e^{\lambda x}$ is $\frac{1}{{\lambda x}}e^{\lambda x}$? True I mean the second one, apologies, let's get it corrected ASAP.

Comment: No, the derivative of $e^{\lambda x}$ is not $\frac{1}{{\lambda x}}e^{\lambda x}$.  True, you "lack mathematical strength".  So, unless you go back to previous courses to gain more mathematical strength, you can do nothing but accept these things without proof.

Comment: $e^ {\lambda x}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integration by parts is not necessary. You can either find the antiderivative directly by noticing that $\frac{d}{dt}e^{-\lambda t} = -\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$, and thus $\int \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \ dt = -e^{-\lambda t}+C$, or you can employ the $u$-substitution $u=-\lambda t$.
With this substitution, we find $du = -\lambda \ dt$, so
$$\int \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \ dt = \int - e^u \ du = - e^u + C = -e^{-\lambda t} +C.$$

Finally, $$\int_0^x \lambda e^{-\lambda t } \ dt = -e^{-\lambda t}\Big|_0^x = -(e^{-\lambda x} - e^0) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Notice that you are integrating over $t$. Therefore you can write$$\int_0^x \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt = \lambda\int_0^x e^{-\lambda t} dt,$$ so you don't need to integrate by parts.

Now what is the derivative of $e^{-\lambda t}$ with respect to $t$? Can you spot the pattern and figure out its integral?

Answer (score 2):

Note,

$$\int_0^x \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt =\int_0^x e^{-\lambda t} d (\lambda t)
=-\int_0^x d(e^{-\lambda t})=-e^{-\lambda t}|_0^x$$ $$=1-e^{-\lambda x}$$